# Неправильно находит последовательность чисел

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность

Нужно создать два потока для двухмерного массива. Один находит в каждой строчке цепочку чисел по возрастанию, второй по убыванию. На экран они должны вывести самые длинные цепочки в каждой строчке. На выходе получаются неправильные последовательности.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>


void random1(int arr[5][100]) {
int i,j;
for(i=0; i<5;i++)
{
for(j=0; j<100;j++)
{
arr[i][j]=rand()%100;
printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
printf("Results:\n");
} 

void* thread_func1(int arr[5][100]){
int i,j;
int l=1, max=1, beg=0, b=0, mel;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(j=1;j<100;j++)
{
if(arr[i][j-1]<arr[i][j])
{
l++;

}
else
{
if(l>max)
{
max=l;
beg=b;
b=j;

l=1;
}
}

}
}
printf("Leng:%d\n",l);
int k= beg+max;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
for(j=beg;j<k;j++){
printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
}printf("\n");
}
}


void* thread_func2(int arr[5][100]){


int i,j;
int l=1, max=1, beg=0, b=0, mel;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(j=1;j<100;j++)
{
if(arr[i][j-1]>arr[i][j])
{
l++;

}
else
{
if(l>max)
{
max=l;
beg=b;
b=j;

l=1;
}
}

}
}
printf("Leng:%d\n",l);
int k= beg+max;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
for(j=beg;j<k;j++){
printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
}printf("\n");
}
}

int main() {

int A[5][100];
int stime;
stime=time(NULL);
srand(stime);
random1(A);
pthread_t k1,k2;
pthread_create(&k1, NULL, (void*)thread_func1,(int*)A);
pthread_join(k1,NULL);
printf("%ld\n",k1);
pthread_create(&k2, NULL, (void*)thread_func2,(int*)A);
pthread_join(k2,NULL);
printf("%ld\n",k2);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int l=1, max=1, beg=0, b=0, mel;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
for(j=1;j<100;j++)
{
```

напишите имя переменной `l` - со смыслом. Например `seqlength`. И при каждой строке считайте по новой. Переменную `beg`, `max` нужно иметь разной при каждой строке.

```
int seqlength, b=0, mel;
int beg[5];
int max[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  seqlength = 1 ; beg[i]=0 ; max[i] = 1 ;
for(j=1;j<100;j++)
{
...
max[i]=l;
beg[i]=b;
b=j;
...
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
int k= beg[i]+max[i];
for(j=beg[i];j<k;j++){
```

Comment: спасибо за совет, всё исправила, но результат такой же

Comment: Теперь переменную `beg` сделать массивом. При каждой строке своё начало...

Comment: а каким образом нужно дальше использовать beg, если он используется как переменная, с которой нужно начинать последовательность?    
вот здесь                                                                                                                             
'max=l;
beg=b;
b=j;'                                                                                                                                                   и здесь 'int k= beg+max;'

Comment: Задача была найти в **каждой** строчке максимально длинную последовательность. В конце, когда выводите результат у каждой строки своя максимальная последовательность и своё начало и свой конец.

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь)